# Need working config for TigerVNC on Fedora 30

Tags: x11, fedora, vnc

I am been fighting with TigerVNC since around Fedora 17.  Every time I started it manually I would get a black screen that would eventually display the gnome desktop and if I started with systemctl it would not work at all.

Recently wiped my system and installed Fedora 30.  Same black screen when I manually start vncserver, but now it never displays the gnome desktop.

These are all default installs.  I get no errors to accompany the black screens.  I am at a loss of what to do.  Could someone provide a working xstartup, config, and command line vncserver command so that I can hopefully get this working?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue today after a fresh `Fedora 30` install.

But, my home directory is from an older install so I'm using my `old ~/.vnc` directory and `~/.Xclients` file.

I got it working by doing the following two things:

1. `sudo echo "DESKTOP=GNOME" > /etc/sysconfig/desktop`
2. Start `vncserver` manually as yourself. If you are already running a desktop on your system then you will have to use a different display number, so the command would be something like `"vncserver :2"`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that did not help.  Could you update your answer and include your xstartup and config files?